# SQL complex pivot query

Tags: sql, pivot

I have 3 tables:

**Companies, Contacts and Company_Contacts**

Table Company_Contact holds the connection between company_id and contact_id, each contact can be related to sevral companies also.

Each company has a different amount of contacts, and I need a query that will bring me the data in this form:

```
company_name  contact_1   contact_2   contact_3   contact_4   contact_5
----------    ---------   ----------  ----------  ---------- -----------
company1       aaa         ddd         ggg        iii         kkk
company2       bbb         eee         hhh        jjj         lll
company3       ccc         fff         NULL        NULL       NULL
```

I don't know for sure if each company has 5 contacts but the request is to bring the top 5 contacts for each company.

I don't how to do it with pivot (if pivot is realy the answer).

How can i create a query to achieve this ?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the presentaion layer/application-level code, assuming you have that.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL is this?

Comment: I can't use any code manipulation, I can only use SQL query...

Comment: Aside from other comment regarding which SQL database, what determines the "top 5" contacts per company.  Is there something like sales revenue?  Most active sales leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the query that I usaed:

```
select company_name, Contact_1, Contact_2, Contact_3, Contact_4, Contact_5
from
(
  select contact.first_name + ' ' + contact.last_name as contact_name,
         company.company_name,
         'Contact_'+
                    cast(row_number() over(partition by relation.company_id 
                         order by relation.contact_id) as varchar(50)) row
  from contacts company
    left join contact_company_relation_additional_information relation
        on company.id = relation.company_id and relation.ContactCompanyRelation_IsActive = 1
    left join contacts contact
        on relation.contact_id = contact.id and contact.is_company = 0 and contact.is_active = 1
 where company.is_company = 1 and company.is_active = 1
) d
pivot
(
  max(contact_name)
  for row in (Contact_1, Contact_2, Contact_3, Contact_4, Contact_5)
) p;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is TSQL as you mention pivot, you can use a combination of a cte to generate a row number and then the pivot.

```
with cte1 as (
    select com.company_id as [Company Id],
           row_number() over (partition by com.company_id order by con.contact_id) as row, 
           [Contact Name] from contacts con
           inner join company_contacts com on com.contact_id=con.contact_id
),
cte2 as (
   select * from cte1 where row < 6
)

select co.[Company Name], 
       c.[1] as contact_1,
       c.[2] as contact_2,
       c.[3] as contact_3,
       c.[4] as contact_4,
       c.[5] as contact_5

from Companies co 
left outer join
(select * 
 from cte2
 pivot (min([Contact Name]) for row in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) x
) c on c.[company id] = co.company_id
```

Comment: did you mean for cte2 to "select * from cte1" (not cte)

Comment: It brings me only 1 contact name, all others are NULL

Comment: I edited the question. Can you please please read it again and give me a new query (-: ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution :

```
/** Part 1 : Ctreate Table of test */
WITH Temp AS(
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact A' ContactName, 80 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact B' ContactName, 11040 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact C' ContactName, 160 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact D' ContactName, 10 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact E' ContactName, 100 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact F' ContactName, 12100 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact G' ContactName, 16800 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company1' CompanyName, 'Contact H' ContactName, 120000 Amount UNION ALL

SELECT 'Company2' CompanyName, 'Contact I' ContactName, 100 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2' CompanyName, 'Contact J' ContactName, 100 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2' CompanyName, 'Contact K' ContactName, 300 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2' CompanyName, 'Contact L' ContactName, 400 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2' CompanyName, 'Contact M' ContactName, 500 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2' CompanyName, 'Contact N' ContactName, 1100 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company2' CompanyName, 'Contact O' ContactName, 1200 Amount UNION ALL

SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact P' ContactName, 8 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact Q' ContactName, 10 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact R' ContactName, 100 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact S' ContactName, 700 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact T' ContactName, 600 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact B' ContactName, 100 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact C' ContactName, 150 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact D' ContactName, 1300 Amount UNION ALL
SELECT 'Company3' CompanyName, 'Contact J' ContactName, 12000 Amount
)

/*Part 2 : Create the SQL Statement*/

SELECT
         CompanyName
        ,contact_1
        ,contact_2
        ,contact_3
        ,contact_4
        ,contact_5
FROM
    (SELECT
             CompanyName
            ,ContactName
            ,CASE Ordre
                WHEN 1 THEN 'contact_1'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'contact_2'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'contact_3'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'contact_4'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'contact_5'
             END Column_pivot
    FROM 
        (SELECT
                *
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyName ORDER BY     Amount     DESC) Ordre from Temp
        ) AS T
    WHERE
        Ordre <= 5 ) AS TT
PIVOT (MAX(ContactName)
    FOR Column_pivot in( contact_1, contact_2, contact_3, contact_4, contact_5 )) as pvt
```

I hope it will help you :)
Good Luck

Comment: instead of the when clause for column_pivot you could just do `'contact_' + cast(row as varchar(1))`

Comment: Anyway we won't go far from 5 otherwise we have to modify the whole sql statement to add the column 'contact_i' in the "SELECT" clause and in the "IN" clause